# Eloquent pluck returns all table rows

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I faced this situation a couple of days ago and wanted to deep dive in it to fully understand why it happens.

There are two models: `Product` and `ProductStatus`:

```php
// Product model
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;

class Product extends Model {

    protected $table = 'products';
    public $timestamps = true;

    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        self::updating(function(Product $model) {
            dd( $model->status->pluck('system_id') );
        });
    }

    public function status(): HasOne {
        return $this->hasOne(ProductStatus::class, 'id', 'status_id');
    }

}
```

```php
// ProductStatus model
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;

class ProductStatus extends Model {

    protected $table = 'product_status';
    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

and each product *hasOne* status and each status has a column called `system_id` that gives us (devs) the meaning of that status (to allow writing better conditions throughout the codebase).

```
// Product Status:
Id  System Id     Description
3   in_stock      In stock
4   out_of_stock  Out of stock
5   undefined     Undefined
```

So far so good.

The strange part happened when I tried to access the product status system_id using the model relation inside the *updating observer*.

Since the observer provides the instance of the model with the changes, I would expect that the line `$model->status->pluck('system_id')` returned only the system_id of the current status the product has (or at least the system_id of the status currently saved in the database). Instead, *pluck* returns the system_id of all the records of the table:
[image: pluck weird return]

What could explain such behavior?

Comment: Why don't you call just `$product->status->system_id`?

Comment: Indeed that would probably work, but my goal with this thread is to understand the pluck() behavior. I agree we don't even need to call it there, but the behavior is so counterintuitive that I wanted to understand it

Answer (score 0):

In your case, when you access the $model->status relationship inside the updating observer, it might be loading all the related records instead of just the current status.
To get the system_id of the current status, you can modify your code as follows:

```
  self::updating(function (Product $model) {
        // Use $model->status to get the related ProductStatus model
        $status = $model->status;
    
        // Check if the status is loaded and not null
        if ($status) {
            // Access the system_id of the current status
            dd($status->system_id);
        }
    });
```

If you still face issues, you can try eagerly loading the status relationship to make sure it's loaded with the correct status:

```
self::updating(function (Product $model) {
    // Eager load the 'status' relationship
    $model->load('status');

    // Access the system_id of the current status
    dd($model->status->system_id);
});
```

I how it can help you :)